How do I connect an app? To a bluetooth speaker twice on the same phone
I'm trying to play music through the speaker and play a game through the headset. I did it before with Samsung A54 dual audio, but I can't figure it out on S24 ultra.
I can't find dual audio on S24, what changed? Is it capable of doing what a less advanced model can do, if so how?
